# Does Diigo have a way to merge tags?

Tags: diigo

I've got too many tags in Diigo.  Is there anyway to merge tags that have been displayed only once, into other tags that you've used many more times?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I get this because I am not sure I understand whether you want this done automatically.

Manually you can just rename the less used tag to the more used tag.

[image: 2 questions tagged c++ two tagged c]

[image: Edit the tag to c]

[image: Merged tag]

[image: All questions now tagged c]

Comment: I was actually thinking more along the lines of selecting two tags, and then selecting one tag to replace with the other tag.

I.E. I click tag_a and I click tag_b, and then when I click merge, and then click tag_a, all of the tag_b entries are replaced with tag_a.

Comment: @lee Yeah, there is no official merge from what I see, but the above (added more screenshots) does this for you. The only extra effort is typing out the parent tag you want the current tag to be merged with. This actually similar to how tag merges work in StackExchange.